# What is the purpose of validation.xml file in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, xml, configuration, validation

What is the purpose of `validation.xml` file in Magento 2? When and where do we use them ?

I see there are couple of `validation.xml` files in Magento 2 directory.

For example:
`vendor/magento/module-customer/etc/validation.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<validation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Validator/etc/validation.xsd">
    <entity name="customer">
        <rules>
            <rule name="check_eav">
                <entity_constraints>
                    <constraint alias="eav_data_validator" class="Magento\Eav\Model\Validator\Attribute\Data" />
                </entity_constraints>
            </rule>
            <rule name="metadata_form_data">
                <entity_constraints>
                    <constraint alias="metadata_data_validator" class="Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\Validator" />
                </entity_constraints>
            </rule>
        </rules>
        <groups>
            <group name="save">
                <uses>
                    <use rule="check_eav"/>
                </uses>
            </group>
            <group name="form">
                <uses>
                    <use rule="metadata_form_data"/>
                </uses>
            </group>
        </groups>
    </entity>

    <entity name="customer_address">
        <rules>
            <rule name="check_eav">
                <entity_constraints>
                    <constraint alias="eav_data_validator" class="Magento\Eav\Model\Validator\Attribute\Data" />
                </entity_constraints>
            </rule>
        </rules>
        <groups>
            <group name="save">
                <uses>
                    <use rule="check_eav"/>
                </uses>
            </group>
        </groups>
    </entity>
</validation>
```

Answer (score 3):

When order is created, Magento will go to
`Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement->placeOrder()` and there
control goes to `submit()` and `submitQuote()` functions.

Then it checks if the customer is not guest (logged in) then it will validate the customer address.

If you dig more, you will see that it creates instances of validator classes by reading `validation.xml` from `/magento/module-customer/etc/validation.xml` and `submitQuote()` function calls `Magento\Quote\Model\Customer\CustomerManagement->validateAddresses()` which calls `Magento\Framework\Validator\Factory->createValidator()` function.

It is passed two arguments defined in `Validation.xml`

1. Entity
2. Group

Validator will find those entities and groups from `Validation.xml`
and creates instances of classes for validation.

Hope this answers the question.